# Variable arguments in C functions

Tags: c, heap-memory, stack-memory

I've read about variable arguments functions "`int func(int, ...)`".
Where do the arguments of these functions get allocated (stack or heap)?

Because I read that the `va_end()` macro frees space assigned to `va_list`, so that word "frees" caught my eyes.

Note: I know that regular functions go to stack, but this type of function is interesting as the number of arguments is not known.

I just want to know for sure that it's not like arrays with no pre-defined space;
we use `malloc()` and `free()` at the end.

Link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_variable_arguments.htm

Comment: Typically variable arguments are pushed on the stack, just like regular arguments.  You don't have to worry about `malloc` or `free`.

Comment: _i just want to know for sure that it's not like arrays with no pre-defined space_: arrays always haves a pre-defined space.

Comment: What difference does it make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[c](/questions/tagged/c) itself doesn't specify things like "heap" or "stack", so programming standard and portable [c](/questions/tagged/c), you should better think in categories of the [c](/questions/tagged/c) standard: static, automatic and dynamic storage.

Nevertheless, in a typical implementation, "automatic storage" translates to "the stack is used for it". This is the case for function arguments and variadic functions are no exception here.

The reason `va_end()` might free some dynamic storage (typically: allocated on the heap) is that the `va_arg()` macro typically needs some context information to find the *next* argument. `va_start()` will allocate the memory **for that information** (not for the arguments themselves) and initialize it in a way so that the first `va_arg()` call returns the first variadic argument.

Note that an implementation of `va_start()` doesn't **have** to allocate memory. `va_list` might be defined in a way that it provides the space for the required context information. But that should be of *no interest at all* to you as the programmer, all the `va_*` stuff is a *black box* for you and if the documentation states "call `va_end()` when done for cleanup", you just do it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Generally platforms have a calling convention. The first few arguments go in registers, the subsequent ones go on the stack. That's deliberately opaque to C code itself. va_start and va_end provide a wrapper round that calling convention, to allow you to access the arguments in sequence by index rather than by name.

Note that you can't build a va_args block at runtime. That's one of the few things C does not allow you to do. You can only generate the block by calling a variable args function.

Also note that in reality variable args lists are used to wrap calls to vsprintf(). You'll almost never find them used for any other purpose in production C code.