# I don't understand something about stack

Tags: c

I am read a passage about stack. But I don't understand the following sentence: *Since the stack grows down, the first parameter will be stored at the lowest address (this inversion of parameters was historically used to allow functions to be passed a variable number of parameters).*

My question is: I think even if the parameters are not inversion-ly stored, we can still allow to pass a variable number of parameters. For example, `sp = sp - 4`, then we `push the first parameter's value onto the stack`, then we do another `sp = sp - 4` and `push second parameter` and so on.

Thanks!

Comment: You're absolutely right. The nature of the stack is irrelevant. See my answer to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56952717/how-does-variable-length-argument-works-in-c/56954307#56954307

Answer (score 2):

The thing is: the function must know where the 1st parameter is, not how many parameters there are.

Imagine you have

```
void fx(int, ...);
```

and

```
fx(2, -1, 42) /* 2 indicates 2 more arguments */;
fx(5, -1, 42, 2, 2, 2);
```

Imagine the stack (growing in whatever direction you want) has "X Y" before the call.

If **pushed in reverse** the stack becomes "X Y 42 -1 2" or "X Y 2 2 2 42 -1 5" and it's easy for the code to pick up **the first argument**: the thing at **the top of the stack**.